# Cordova + Xcode + Change

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

My problem is about changes in xcode for a new version of a IOS app.

Step 1 :

In terminal : cordova build ios.

Step 2 :

I open it on xcode (.xcode file)

Step 3 :

I do a archive build (for dev test)

Step 4 :

I do a change on my controller.js for example in xcode. (simple alert('test'))
Step 5 :

**I RE do a archive build... But it's like nothing has changed.**

Where is my problem ?
Do I have to rebuild cordova build ios EACH time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you open the .xcode file in the project structure you will see the **Staging** folder which has www folder of the project.

Changes will only reflect when you have done the changes in **staging** folder.
then just run the app through xcode no need for any cli command.

hope this will help

Comment: I didnt see this folder ! If I change something here, will it be saved of my project files ? (like if I do a cordova build android..)

Comment: no, it won't , changes you do in staging folder will be applied in xcode only, if you run any CLI command your changes will be gone.

Comment: for the changes to persist you do have the change in the www folder of your cordova project as well.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks you. I have my final answer.

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

For propagating changes you just have to run

`cordova prepare ios`, it's going to be faster that a full build.

BTW, you don't need to archive, just hit the run button (triangle) and if you have a device connected it will install and run the app